# Flex:- After rotation from center how fit image in a container box (Scale or resize according to container box)

Tags: apache-flex, rotation, scaling

I am developing a flex application.

In which I have a to rotate image from center in its container box.

There is another container box(Named tool) is attached to the image, that contains some buttons at corner.
Currently I am rotating these tool box and it is rotating successfully with image, I am using below code for rotation :-

```
var imgMatrix:Matrix = imgOwner.transform.matrix; 
            var centerX:Number = imgOwner.width / 2; 
            var centerY:Number = imgOwner.height / 2; 
            var centerPoint:Point = new Point(centerX, centerY); 
            var transformPoint:Point= imgMatrix.transformPoint(centerPoint); 

            imgMatrix.translate(-transformPoint.x, -transformPoint.y);                      
            imgMatrix.rotate(newRotationInDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
            imgMatrix.translate(+transformPoint.x, +transformPoint.y);
            imgOwner.transform.matrix = imgMatrix;
```

Image appears inside these imgOwner tool.

I only want to fit these tool with image after rotation in the main container.

Please advice, thanks in advance.